# getElementByID work in firefox, but not in IE & Chrome

Tags: javascript, html

```
function change1() { 
document.getElementById("video").src = document.myvid1.vid_select.options[document.myvid1.vid_select.selectedIndex].value
}

<form name="myvid1">
<select id="vid_select" onChange="change();">
<option value="http://www.youtube.com/v/nN8Si5LKyY?autoplay=1">Test1</option>
<option value="http://www.youtube.com/v/CdKUtZIDzEg?autoplay=1">Test2</option>
</select>
</form>

<object width="650" height="450">
<embed id="video" src="http://www.youtube.com/v/IiJx4a1cxRk" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="650" height="450" />
</object>
```

The above code can work in Firefox, but not in IE & Chrome.

Comment: I want to select the source from drop down menu, after that the video will play.

Comment: Are you aware that your select is calling change() but you defined your function as change1() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function change() 
    { 
        var html = '<object width="650" height="450"> <embed id="video" src="';

        html += document.myvid1.vid_select.options[document.myvid1.vid_select.selectedIndex].value;
        html += '" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="650" height="450"/>';

        document.getElementById("div-video").innerHTML = html;
    }
</script>

<form name="myvid1">
    <select id="vid_select" onChange="change();">
        <option value="http://www.youtube.com/v/IiJx4a1cxRk">Test1</option>
        <option value="http://www.youtube.com/v/CdKUtZIDzEg?autoplay=1">Test2</option>
    </select>
</form>

<div id="div-video">
    <object width="650" height="450">
        <embed id="video" src="http://www.youtube.com/v/IiJx4a1cxRk" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="650" height="450" />
    </object>
</div>
```

Comment: Please explain in your answer what you changed and why this code works

Comment: I added <script></script> tags around the function so they'll run.  The <embed> tag doesn't allow setting of src attribute.  I just have IE 10 and Chrome installed and it doesn't work there so I enclosed the <embed> tag in a <div>.  The change() function just recreates the entire <object> and <embed> tags inside the <div> thus forcing the video to load. I just noticed I forgot to close the <object> tag in the function but it still works.  Alternatively you can also just wrap the <embed> around the <div> and recreate it rather than doing <object> and <embed>.

Comment: This solution would be made cleaner by passing the value of the `select` as a variable directly to the `change()` function, as I did in my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Try this, to avoid any potential browser-specific selector confusion:

```
<script>
function change(newsrc) {
    document.getElementById('video').src = newsrc;
}
</script>

<form name='myvid1'>
    <select id='vid_select' onchange='change(this.value)'>
        <option value="http://www.youtube.com/v/nN8Si5LKyY?autoplay=1">Test1</option>
        <option value="http://www.youtube.com/v/CdKUtZIDzEg?autoplay=1">Test2</option>
    </select>
</form>

<object width='650' height='450'>
    <embed id="video" src="http://www.youtube.com/v/IiJx4a1cxRk" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="650" height="450" />
</object>
```

Comment: Not sure why this was down voted, but the solution here is much cleaner. @DiMono, I would how ever explain your answer a bit more.

Comment: All I did was pass the value of the `select` as a variable, rather than having to fetch it from within the function. It was more meant as an interim step to remove some moving parts, but I definitely think it's a cleaner way to handle fetching the value.